# Recursive prompt returns undefined

Tags: javascript

I noticed something quite odd this morning when I was trying to implement an endless prompting system.

The following code returns 2 different outputs under 2 scenarios:

**Scenario 1:** Enter number on first prompt and ok

**Output 1:** `number that was entered`

---

**Scenario 2:** Cancel first prompt then enter number and ok

**Output 2:** `undefined`

---

I'm perplexed as to why this is happening. Firstly, how does this return undefined when I am checking for that in the if statement? Second, I was under the impression that in JavaScript undefined means a variable has been declared but has not yet been assigned and in this case I am assigning the `var number`.

```js
var number = null;
number = Prompt();
$("p").html("Number was " + number);

function Prompt()
{
  var input = prompt("Enter a number", "");
  if(input === null || input === "" || input === undefined || isNaN(input))
      Prompt();
  else
      return input;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p></p>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only one code path returns a value, make it return from the recursive call. In JavaScript if a function ends without a return statement its return is `undefined`

```
function Prompt()
{
  var input = prompt("Enter a number", "");
  if(input === null || input === "" || input === undefined || isNaN(input))
      return Prompt();
  else
      return input;
}
```

Comment: You should mention that only a string is returned from `prompt`. `isNaN('anystring')` will always return `true`, whereas `Number.isNaN` will only return `true` if `input` is actually `NaN`. Recommend `parseInt` etc.

Comment: @naomik: not true.  `isNaN("      ") === false`  I don't know why it returns false, but perhaps you could try `isNaN(parseFloat(input))`

Comment: @ThomasF thanks, I didn't know that, I only bothered to remember that `window.isNaN` is a piece of garbage. `Number.isNaN` is much more usable.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification on why it is returning undefined I did not know that. As for the code path not returning a value.. 100% oversight by me - I legitimately knew about that haha - whoops - fail. Thanks.

Comment: actually you can do.

Comment: return isNaN(input.trim() || undefined) ? prompt() : input;

Answer (score 3):

`window.prompt` always returns a string or `null` so don't bother checking for `undefined`, or `isNaN`

Also, since `window.prompt` returns a string, you will need to use `window.parseInt` in order to reliably convert it to a Number.

```js
function Prompt() {
  var n = window.parseInt(window.prompt("Enter a number"), 10)

  if (Number.isNaN(n))
    return Prompt()
  else
    return n
}

alert("Your number is: " + Prompt())
```

Answer (score -1):

When the first prompt is cancelled another Prompt() iteration is called, but it's return value is not captured anywhere. The first iteration then returns the original undefined return value.

Musa's answer shows one way to fix this. Another would be:

```
function Prompt() {
    var input = null;
    while(input === null) {
        input = prompt("Enter a number", "");
    }
    return input;
 }
```